# Using timer in controller rail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
#controller
def main_unit_clock_set
    loop do
        puts "count...."

        @cooltech_time=@cooltech_time+1
        sleep 1
    end 
end
```

I have this code so far, but it only puts count.... every 1s and don't render/reload my view in main_unit_clock_set.html.erb, how can I fix that?

Comment: And what do you want the code to do?

Comment: You are trying to solve a problem that should be solved with javascript rather than a rails controller.

Comment: this code will loop forever, which will prevent the page from rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need use javascript to call rails action periodically

```
setInterval(get_ajax, 1000);

        function get_ajax(){
             $.ajax('/main_unit_clock_set', {
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(result) {
                    if(result > 0){
                        $('#div_1').text("See "+result+" new messages");
                        $('#div_1').show();
                    }
                    else{
                        $('#div_1').css('display', 'none');
                    }
                     },
                error: function() {
                    // alert("Error")
                }
            });       

        }
```